# Trigonometric system and orthogonality

Tags: fourier-transform, orthogonality

[image]

I'm having trouble understanding the 2nd line. So, just looking at the 3rd line (4.9), I can see that this is true, ie, each term in the series will $= 1$ if $j=k$ by orthogonality of the trig system, and summing that N times gives N if $j = k$, but all terms 0 if $j \neq k$

But then, using the partial sum equation in line 2, if $j = k$, the partial sum is $\frac{0}{0}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the given proof, there were two minor omissions, which may have been the source of your doubts about the proof.

**First omission . . .**

The line in the proof which started with
$$
\text{For}\;\,0\le j\le N-1\;\text{. . .}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\;
$$
should have been
$$
\text{For}\;\,0\le j,k\le N-1\;\text{. . .}
\qquad\qquad\;\;\;\;\;
$$

**Second omission . . .**

Let $N$ be a positive integer, and let $r\in\mathbb{C}$.

The stated formula should have been
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}r^n
=
\begin{cases}
{\Large{\frac{1-r^N}{1-r}}}&&\text{if}\;r\ne 1\\[4pt]
N&&\text{if}\;r=1\\
\end{cases}
\qquad\;\;\;
$$
With those corrections, let
$$
r=e^{2i\pi(j-k)/N}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
$$
Then for the case $j=k$, we have $r=1$, so the identity
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\left[e^{2i\pi(j-k)/N}\right]^n=N
\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;\;
$$
is immediate.

For the case $j\ne k$, since $0\le j,k\le N-1$, it follows that $2\pi(j-k)/N$
is not an integer multiple of $2\pi$.

Hence $r\ne 1$, so
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\left[e^{2i\pi(j-k)/N}\right]^n\\[4pt]
=&\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}r^n\\[4pt]
=&\frac{1-r^N}{1-r}\\[4pt]
=&\;0\;\;\;\text{[since $r^N=e^{2i\pi(j-k)}=1$, and $1-r\ne 0$]}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Well large part of the issue seems that the first line is completly false. The identity does not hold when r=1 and also does not seem to hold when r is negative. Since this is a proof such information about r should be contained in hypothesis, and in that case the case of j=k has to be treated separately.

Comment: huh ok, weird..

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle the case $j=k$ separately. It is obvious that the sum is $N$ when $j=k$ because each term is just $1$.

The line just above (4.9) is not valid when $j=k$.

Comment: For the partial sum equation in line 2, if $j = k$, we get $\frac{1-e^0}{1-e^0} = \frac{0}{0}$. But clearly that is not correct?

Comment: What I am saying is for $j=k$ prove (4.9) without referring to previous line. Just see what LHS is.

Comment: I get that just looking at (4.9) with $j=k$, we get sum = N. But if we use equation in line 2, we don't get it. My question is why is there a discrepancy?

Comment: Equation in line 2 is not valid when $r=k$. Division by $0$ is not allowed in Mathematics. So there is a mistake in that line.

Comment: oh ok. so equation 2 is just a "general" form, but when we are considering j =k, it's not applicable because we divide by zero.